# Twitter Bootstrap: switching footers based on viewport

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In my app, there is a different footer for signed in users vs those who are signed out (guest users).

In mobile devices (portrait viewport; iOS specfically) is it good practice to use the Bootstrap utility classes (`hidden-phone`, `hidden-desktop`, etc) for displaying two different footers?

For example, the footer for my signed in users and those using a phone, I am wanting to see a different footer because some of the elements in the footer are "lost" because of the way the footer resizes for the smaller viewports.

Answer (score 0):

As they note themselves in the Boottsrap [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html):

"*Use on a limited basis and avoid creating entirely different versions of the same site. Instead, use them to complement each device's presentation.*"

I was mindful of that with my own site, but I did make a single exception for two different presentations of my homepage. The design that warranted this exception is a one off and doesn't happen anywhere else on the site, so I felt comfortable with the exception.

It seems like your case is also limited in scope, so you should be OK with it. Just prefer not doing that if it isn't too much trouble, and if you do, resist the urge to keep doing it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for the help! I know that the ideology behind bootstrap (or any other front-end framework) is to assist with responsive markup and providing the best UX for all users, however, I am curious how some websites get around provided a different UX for those who are on mobile vs web (using a framework that is)

Comment: Some sites do of course create different versions, but Bootstrap uses `responsive.css` so you shouldn't have to. With my site, an idiosyncrasy with my current design on the home page compelled me to make the exception I described, but the entire rest of the site looks good on all devices.